# Robust packages installation and updating on Cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud, paclets, development

Questions:

- What is an idiomatic way to upload/install a paclet in own Wolfram Cloud account?
- What is an idiomatic way to update/overwrite existing paclet?

It is not tough but:

- PacletManager works in 'read-only' mode so `PacletInstall` can't be used
- While `CreateDirectory` and `CopyDirectory` work well to set a new one I failed to update a package this way. Even with `DeleteDirectory[.., DeleteContents->True]` there were traces of nested directory structure which prompted errors when `CopyDirectory` was called again. Otoh I could not delete them directly with DeleteDirecotry and I could not access them via browser interface because the top one was already missing from the file menu...

Again a basic use case is a pain to perform.

Probably assembling a simple code that does it will not take long, but only if you know the 'proper' way.

related: [Clean package update for API/FormFunctions on Wolfram Cloud](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147330/5478)

Comment: I don't know if I have a terribly idiomatic way. I effectively just use `CopyFile` and update the `PacletSite.m` file programmatically. Most of my work has gone into simplifying and generalizing the paclet construction.

Comment: @b3m2a1 I think there isn't any and anything that works will be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The rule of thumb is:

for a cloud file system related actions use `CloudObject` wrapper for files/dirs whenever it is possible. One can do a lot of deviations e.g.:

```
CloudEvaluate @ DeleteDirectory["test/dir", DeleteContents->True]
```

And it more or less works, untill the next time you upload something in the same place. In cases of nested directories, inner ones are somehow cached and it is not possible to overwrite it unless you `DeleteDirectory @ CloudObject @ "test/dir/innerdir"` directly.

#### TL;DR;

Quick package cleanup:

```
DeleteDirectory[
  CloudObject["Base/Applications/`packageName`"]
, DeleteContents -> True
]
```

You can use `FileNameJoin` and `$UserBaseDirectory` but then you need to evaluate via cloud because your OS can be different than Cloud's linux.

Quick package installation:

```
CopyDirectory[
  "local/dir/of/thePackage"
, CloudObject["Base/Applications/thePackage"]
]
```

Seems to be elementary but deviations from mentioned rule will cost you a lot of time.