# What is the recommended path to install packages on Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

On Desktop, I can install a custom package in the `Applications` directory under `AddOns`. This path appears in `$Path` and loading the package is successful.

On Cloud, I tried to install a package in `` "Base`Applications`" `` like I would on Desktop, but the only way loading the package has worked is if I run `` Prepend[$ContextPath, "Base`Applications`"] `` at the beginning of a notebook. The path to `Base/Applications` exists on the `$Path`.

Can the context be set automatically? Where is one supposed to install a package? Is this a bug?

Comment: You can install them normally in `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications` just like in Desktop Mathematica I believe.

Comment: Does it answer your question? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175543/5478?

Comment: This helps, but it seems there is a bug. I have checked the $Path and it contains the cloud path. I moved the package file to that location, but I have seen inconsistent results unless I run Prepend as mentioned. Even this fails on the mobile app sometimes

Comment: @DanKowalczyk it is hard to help without a clear description of steps that lead to a problem

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake by trying to import the context that the file defines, not the file itself. D'oh!

The package I tried to import is defined in a file named `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications/Package.m`. The context it defines is `` Package`Main` ``. I was running `` Needs["Package`Main`"] `` because as a newbie I thought imports must refer to the context, however this fails.

I am now able to import successfully by simply specifying the filename as `` Needs["Package`"] ``. This works because the `$Path` contains `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications/`.

Comment: You could expand on this giving a proper answer to your original question (basically saying that `$UserBaseDirectory` works) and then mention what happened to you.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing this and for your suggestion. I added some more details.