# How to install NCAlgebra to Mathematica Online

Tags: wolfram-cloud, mathematica-online, ncalgebra

New Mathematica user, attempting to install NCAlgebra to Mathematica Online. Following instructions from https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/blob/master/README.md , I first tried:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NCAlgebra/NC/master/NCExtras/NCWebInstall.m", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
```

This fails with:

> Transfering$Failed[Unzip`Private`getContentLength[]]Round[-----------------------------------------]1048576MBfrom:
> https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/archive/master.zip
> Pleasebepatient...

Java
::excptn
:AJavaexceptionoccurred:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:Couldnotinitializeclasssun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContextatjava.base/java.lang.Class.forN…eflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)atjava.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566).

> Somethingwentwrong.Aborting...

I also tried:

```
CloudImport["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NCAlgebra/NC/master/NCExtras/NCWebInstall.m", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"];
```

which fails with or without the second argument returning:
CloudObject: The URL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NCAlgebra/NC/master/NCExtras/NCWebInstall.m is not valid.

Eventually, I downloaded the content locally, compressed and uploaded it Base/Applications, and extracted it using:

```
dir=CreateDirectory["NC"]
ExtractArchive["NC-master.tgz",dir, OverwriteTarget->True]
FileNames[]
```

which returns {._NC,NC-master.tgz}
._NC is new, not sure why it's not just NC... also running

```
<< NC`
```

per the readme just returns:
Cannot open NC`.

I'm not really sure where to go from here, just trying to get the hang of NCAlgebra and see if it suits my purposes before my trial expires. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like the online Java engine will not let you unzip the file. Unfortunately I do not have access to online MMA, but if you can upload files I would recommend you simply download the package from github and upload it to your cloud account manually. Just make sure that the base directory is called `NC`. Let me know if that works.

Update #1:

Alternatively, we now have an experimental version of NCAlgebra that is going to be distributed as a paclet. See

~~[https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/tree/v6.0.0~](https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC/tree/v6.0.0%7E)~

for details. That should work online and with newer versions of mathematica without glitches.

Update #2:

I tested the paclet version online and it seems to work without problems, even though there are various messages that pop out when loading NCAlgebra. Those seem to be coming from the package Notation, which is a native mathematica package, which seems to be having some trouble detecting the platform it is running in online.

Update #3:

I disabled the use of the Notation package on the cloud. It is not a functional requirement, it is just used when the pretty output options of NCSetOutput are used. I will put it back when the issue with Notation is solved.

Update #4:

v6.0.0 is now the main release. See

https://github.com/NCAlgebra/NC

for details.

Comment: Have you considered distributing it as a paclet?

Comment: BTW Mathematica Online can be used with a free account (within limits)

Comment: I will look into the packlet format next time I pack a distribution. The free limits prevent me from uploading files so I could not test what I suggested :)

Comment: What you suggested should work, I tested this in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Szabolcs!

Comment: @MauriciodeOliveira thanks for your answer! Unfortunately the online system does not allow folder uploads either, so it becomes a giant mess trying to upload the entire repo without any structure. 

When I get some free time I'll see if I can figure out another expedient way to achieve the upload into NC directly.

Thanks again!

Comment: Thak you as well @Szabolcs! You actually answered a similar question

 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91194/installing-packages-on-mathematica-online

which is what prompted me to try the archive method. Not sure why it isn't working for me, but it did seem like the silver bullet which would solve the inability to upload folders.

Comment: BTW, that is a problem now too in 13.2.0.

Comment: We have now an experimental paclet version of NCAlgebra. I will update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @MauriciodeOliveira Congrets on release of 6.0.0.

Comment: Thank you @Валерий Заподовников!