# Using the Notation Package in Wolfram Cloud

Tags: wolfram-cloud, notation

I'm trying to work with a notebook created in the Desktop app using Wolfram Cloud. This notebook uses `Symbolize` from the `Notation` package to keep a lot of notation more simple. How can I import this package on Wolfram Cloud? Do I have to do what is described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91194/installing-packages-on-mathematica-online)? If that's the case, where would I find the files for the package?

Edit: When I try importing the package the way I'd do it in the Desktop client I get the following series of errors:

```
StringMatchQ: String or lists of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[$Failed,*Windows*]
StringMatchQ: String or lists of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[$Failed,*Mac*]
StringMatchQ: String or lists of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[$Failed,*Windows*]
```

Comment: I believe that Notation is built-in.  Try it and see?

Comment: I get the error ```StringMatchQ[$Failed,*Windows*]``` and two other similar errors for Mac and Windows again. I'll edit this into the question.

Comment: The package is there but you can't use it because cloud notebooks don't support boxes/standard form as input and everything is just input form.

Comment: That makes sense, bummer. Thank you very much.